# boot window 7 from external HD

Tags: windows-7, boot, external-hard-drive, boot-camp

I run windows 7 using bootcamp on my mac. I have backed up my windows 7 partition using driveimage xml to an external HD creating an exact clone. I would now like to try to boot windows directly off the external HD.  However, I cannot get the computer to recognize my HD (by holding down the option key) to boot from it.
I have created a bootsector using bootsect and it still doesn't work.
Since I have bootcamp I can't either seem to get the typical windows menu to boot from usb.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have another Windows system you can get access to, I would check that the Cloned Image isn't compressed in any way.  In other words, check that all the folders and files are where they need to be as well as that they are the correct size.  Also verify that your computer supports booting off an External Drive. I haven't used any Apple/Macintosh products, so I am clueless as to what bootcamp is, but atleast here is a starting place for you.

Sources:

Working on my own system's, and working in a Computer Repair store/MSP.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. I used rEFIt to change my mac boot loader and from their booted from my external HD.  I seems mac doesn't allow by default to boot windows from USB.